# liquid layout with two columns and a footer

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to build a liquid layout with two columns and a fixed footer at the bottom. I already take some help here, and I have one example above.

http://jsfiddle.net/kpDDM/18/

The problem on my example is that it has a fixed height. When I move to 100% heigh on my content div, the content collaps.

Answer (score 1):

Do you need something like this : http://jsfiddle.net/kpDDM/44/

HTML

```
<div class="all">
    <div class="content">
      <div class="left">&nbsp;</div>  
      <div class="right">&nbsp;</div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.all {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

body,html{
    height:100%;
}

.content {
    display:inline-block;
    height: 90%;
    width: 100%;
}

.left {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    width: 60%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: red;
}

.right {
    display:inline-block;
    float: left;
    width: 40%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: blue;
}

.footer {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 10%;
    background-color: green;
}
```

**Explanation**

The problem is that the body tag does not have 100% itself. You have to assign that to body and then it'll work. In the above example I assumed that the content + footer share 100% of the height. 90% + 10%

Comment: Hi, I want a fixed height footer.

Comment: you can add a fixed height foote by just replacing the footer's height with the height you want...but the content's height cannot be set to the remaining height just using css.

However, if you still add 100% height to content, it'll still work.

Comment: There is a little problem when I put very much content on left div. Take a look: http://jsfiddle.net/kpDDM/45/

Comment: Unfortunately, I have to use a pre-defined layout, and I cant put the scroll bar on the left div. In the desired behavior, all the content div should expand.